# function pointer usage in c

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct file{
        int a;
        int b;
        int (*fp) (int ,int);
        };
static int sum(int a, int b)
{
        return(a+b);
}
void main()
{
        struct file var;


        int sum1=0;

        var.fp=&sum;
        sum1=fp(2,4);
        printf("\nsum is  %d ",sum1);
}
```

how to call the function..?? i am getting an error called as undefined reference to fp..???

Comment: I'd recommend removing the linux tag on this post since linux has nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 6):

Since its a member of the structure you have to qualify it:

```
sum1 = var.fp( 2, 4 );
```

Answer (score 6):

You meant to say `sum1 = var.fp(...)` or `sum1 = (*var.fp)(...)` but you typed `fp(...)`. C implicitly defined an external fp() for you to call. The compiler has to do this in order to compile legacy C code.

Use `cc -Wall ...` to generate errors for missing forward declarations.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried changing:

> sum1=fp(2,4);

To:

> sum1=var.fp(2,4);

?

Comment: Good.  Don't forget to mark the answer to the question as "accepted" (the green check mark).  Doing so will make it more likely that others will answer the questions you ask in the future.